# 2 exceptions when trying to make async HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am writing an MVC Web API the make async HttpWebRequest calls.  I am getting 2 different exceptions.  Below is the method I am using.

The 1st exception is:  "This stream does not support seek operations." and it is happening on the responseStream.

The 2nd exception is: "timeouts are not supported on this stream" and that is happening on the MemoryStream content.

What am I doing wrong?  I have been Googling but not really finding any solution.

Thanks,

Rhonda

[image]

[image]
    private async Task GetHtmlContentAsync(string requestUri, string userAgent, string referrer, bool keepAlive, TimeSpan timeout, bool forceTimeoutWhileReading, string proxy, string requestMethod, string type)
        {
            //string to hold Response
            string output = null;

```
        //create request object
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        var content = new MemoryStream();
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.KeepAlive = keepAlive;
        request.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");
        request.Timeout = (Int32)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = (Int32)timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
        request.Referer = referrer;
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;

        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);
                    }
                }

                var sr = new StreamReader(content);
                output = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output = string.Empty;
            var message = ("The API caused an exception in the " + type + ".\r\n " + requestUri + "\r\n" + ex);
            Logger.Write(message);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: What are the stack frames for your exceptions?

Comment: I assume you mean the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, the stack trace.

Comment: The real issue that I am having is the call GetResponseStream returns a string of html which is what I expect when I remover the copytoasync and use using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream)){output = sr.ReadToEnd();} but the result I always get from the application that is calling the API is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" when it returns. 

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: content.Position = 0;

Comment: I fixec the issue by adding content.Position = 0 before new StreamReader line.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding

content.Position = 0

before new StreamReader line.   Now I just need to get it work with GZip compression.

Rhonda